# Add another attachments column to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, modern-experience, attachments

I've used the Asset manager template to for a list of the companies machines. This template has the attachments column enabled. This column is used for all documents for the machine.

I would like to have another column where I can add all the images for a certain machine, much like the attachments column but for images. Ideally with a preview / thumnail function.

How can I add another column, that allows me to add multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you cannot add new attachments column in a SharePoint Online list.

---

SharePoint Online lists supports image column types, read [all you need to know about New Image column type in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/).

Unfortunately, this column type supports adding **single image** per column.

As you want to add multiple files/images, you have to use the document library & connect it with the list.

Two ways:

1. Create lookup from SharePoint list to document library & add files in library.
2. Create a folder in library with unique column value from list (maybe list item ID) & add files to that folder.

Additionally you can provide the hyperlink to that library/folder in your list either manually using hyperlink column Or using JSON Formatting. So that users can easily navigate to library from the list.