# Can a Second Attachment Column be Added to SP List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, attachments

I have a work order app.

There is a main work order and a secondary work order (two separate screens).

The base data (names, places, contact info), is the same for both.

The primary inspection may lead to findings that require a second and associated inspection, which is entered on the secondary work order screen.

I've got a Patch uploading all of the data from both forms, including the attachments (images taken by a camera control on form 1). There is also a camera control on the secondary work order screen.

Is there a way to create a separate/second 'Attachment' column in the SharePoint for the secondary images taken? I can't find 'Attachments' as an option in the 'Create Column' of the SharePoint list setup.

How do I upload the secondary attachments/images and associated them with the secondary work and not the primary work?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of adding a second Attachments column, and I don't think you can.

I would suggest using a naming convention to either prefix or suffix the file names so you can tell which work order they belong to.

Something like

```
1_some file name.jpg
1_some other file.jpg
2_second work order file.jpg
2_another file.jpg
```

or

```
some file name_1.jpg
some other file_1.jpg
second work order file_2.jpg
another file_2.jpg
```

---

After seeing your code you posted in your comment, what I'm suggesting would be to edit what you have there, but do some string concatenation to put a prefix on the file name.  It could either be in the `Set` or in the `Collect`, the way you have it there.  You could either do

```
Set(varJobImage, "1_" & GUID());
```

and leave the `Collect` as is, or leave the `Set` as is and change the `Collect` to be

```
Collect(
    NewReportVehicleImageCollection,
    {
        DisplayName: "1_" & varJobImage & ".jpg",
        Id: "1_" & varJobImage & ".jpg",
        Value: Camera1.Photo
    }
);
```

Then you'll know any attachments that start with "1_" are for the main work order.

Do the same with "2_" for the secondary work order.

Actually, I found [this article](https://www.matthewdevaney.com/strings-a-better-way-to-concatenate-text-strings-in-power-apps/) that talks about different ways to concatenate strings in Power Apps, and given that using the `$` string interpolation syntax is possible, I think it would make your code much easier to read if you used that, and moved all of the string concatenation into the `Set`, and not do any of it in the `Collect`:

```
Set(varJobImage, $"1_{GUID()}.jpg");
Collect(
    NewReportVehicleImageCollection,
    {
        DisplayName: varJobImage,
        Id: varJobImage,
        Value: Camera1.Photo
    }
);
```

Nice and clean and easy to see what's going on. :)

Comment: My main camera control has the following in the OnSelect, that creates a collection that I reference in the Gallery on screen for review before Patching.

Are you suggesting editing the below, or creating another with different names, to solve my problem?

Set(
    varJobImage,
    GUID()
);
Collect(
    NewReportVehicleImageCollection,
    {
        DisplayName: varJobImage & ".jpg",
        Id: varJobImage & ".jpg",
        Value: Camera1.Photo
    }
);

Comment: @CurtisETroutt updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

By default SharePoint lists support only one attachments column and you cannot add new attachments column in a SharePoint Online list.

---

SharePoint Online lists supports image column types, read [all you need to know about New Image column type in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/).

Unfortunately, this column type supports adding **single image** per column. So, if you are capturing only one image in primary/secondary form, you can use image column in list.

Also, as per [Power Apps can now display images from SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/05/25/power-apps-can-now-display-images-from-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/), currently image columns only support "Read/display" operations in Power apps.

So, you have to first upload the image to any document library/Site Assets library and then update image column using REST APIs (using Power automate flow).

You have to set the image field in this format:

```
Image: {
    'fileName':'Power Apps logo.jpg',
    'serverRelativeUrl':'/sites/MySite/SiteAssets/Lists/dbc6f551-252b-462f-8002-c8f88d0d12d5/Power%20Apps%20logo.jpg'
}
```

---

If you want to add multiple files/images, you have to use the document library & connect it with the list.

Two ways:

1. Create lookup from SharePoint list to document library & add files in library.
2. Create a folder in library with unique column value from list (maybe list item ID) & add files to that folder.

Additionally you can provide the hyperlink to that library/folder in your list either manually using hyperlink column Or using JSON Formatting. So that users can easily navigate to library from the list view in SharePoint.

**Similar thread**: [Add another attachments column to sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/301407/add-another-attachments-column-to-sharepoint-list/301414#301414)